# The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'

Tags: development, web-config, wcf

I am receiving the following error from my SharePoint 2010 service application:

```
The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'
```

This code is being thrown from the my channel.

```
 public string ConvertToTLForm(string inputDocument, string tipAndLeadLibrary, string siteCollectionURL)
{

    // execute the call against the service app
    ExecuteOnChannel("ConvertToTLForm",
        delegate(ITipAndLeadAPIContract channel)
        {
            channel.ConvertToTLForm(inputDocument, tipAndLeadLibrary, siteCollectionURL);
        });

    return "";
}
```

Anyone have any ideas on why this is being thrown? There are a few similar threads on stackoverflow.com but none of them seemed to provide the answers I was looking for.

Here is my client.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <client>
            <endpoint  address=""
                name="http"
                      binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="TLAPIServiceHttpBinding"
                      contract="AF.TipAndLeadAPI.ITipAndLeadAPIContract" />
        </client>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="TLAPIServiceHttpBinding">

                    <security authenticationMode="IssuedTokenOverTransport" allowInsecureTransport="true" />
                    <textMessageEncoding>
                        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="204857600" maxArrayLength="209715200" />
                    </textMessageEncoding>
                    <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="216268800" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" useDefaultWebProxy="false" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="C#" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="TLAPITypeBehaviors" >
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service name="AF.TipAndLeadAPI.TipAndLeadAPIServiceApplication" behaviorConfiguration="TLAPITypeBehaviors">
                <endpoint binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="TLAPIServiceHttpBinding"
                          contract="AF.TipAndLeadAPI.ITipAndLeadAPIContract"
                          address="" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="TLAPIServiceHttpBinding">
                    <security authenticationMode="IssuedTokenOverTransport" allowInsecureTransport="true" />
                    <textMessageEncoding>
                        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2048576000" maxArrayLength="2097152000" />
                    </textMessageEncoding>
                    <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2162688" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" useDefaultWebProxy="false" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, I reverted my Virtual Machine to a previous state, executed the exact same code and everything worked fine. Still not sure why exactly I got the above error, perhaps something was lingering in my GAC or some old assembly wasn't getting full removed. If anyone has any thoughts, please share.